# Unir Arreglo de Caracteres en una sola variable php

Tags: php

necesito hacer lo que dice el título del asunto, el detalle es que se trata de un arreglo que tiene tamaño máximo 10 por lo no sé cuando ingresarán un tamaño diferente es decir 10 no es obligatorio pero si el máximo, soy nuevo en el lenguaje.

Ir al final del código:

```html
<?php
 
 function sevent(int $c){
 if(($c/7)>17) 
 return true;
 else
 return false;
 }

 function sprimo(int $b){
   $d=1;  $p=0;

 do{
 if($b % $d == 0)
 $p++;   
 $d++;
  }while($d < $b+1);

 if($p==2) 
 return true;
 else
 return false;
 }



function lenner(string $a)
 {
    $sz = strlen($a); 
 $vector; 
 $cat; 
 $b;
 $i;
    $x;

 for($i=0; $i<$sz; $i++)
  $vector[$i]=ord($a[$i]);
  
 for($i=0; $i<$sz; $i++){
  $x=$vector[$i];  
 if(sprimo($x)){
  $vector[$i]+=5;
  $cat[$i]=1;
  goto jump;
  }
 if(sevent($x)){
  $vector[$i]-=7;
  $cat[$i]=2;
  goto jump;
  }
 else{
  $vector[$i]+=9;
  $cat[$i]=3;
 } 
 jump:

 }
 for($i=0; $i<$sz; $i++)
  $b[$i]=chr($vector[$i]);

 $sub2 =  $b[0] . $b[1] . $b[2] . $b[3] . $b[4] . $b[5] . $b[6] . $b[7] . $b[8] . $b[9] ;
 
 return $sub2;
 }
```

Un millón de gracias

Comment: No entendí la pregunta. Y, dado que es un código del siglo pasado (años 1900), quizá sería bueno que cuentes un poco lo que quieres hacer a ver si modernizamos un poco. Desde que empecé en la informática me dijeron que `goto` era una sentencia a evitar y me parece increíble ver en 2019 en código PHP usando `goto`.

Comment: Buen día porfavor ilustrame, como hago para repetir el for sin que se procese más de una decisión, es que soy nuevo en el lenguaje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos por ayudarme, cambié las condiciones para mi función de encriptación, la respuesta a mi pregunta es esta:

```html
 for($i=0; $i<$sz; $i++){
  $b[$i]=chr($vector[$i]);
  $sub2 .=$b[$i];
 }
 return $sub2;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Usa la función sizeOf()

La solución simple a ello es hacer un ciclo con el tamaño del arreglo y los valores para evitar manejar únicamente los 10 que mencionas.

```
for($cont=0;$cont<sizeof($b);$cont++)
  $variable+=(string)$b[$cont];
```

Esto al final de tu código. Así mismo, cada caracter del arreglo `$b` será emulado como una cadena y sumado a tu `$variable`.

Comment: Hacía mucho tiempo que no veía código PHP con 'goto'..si me permites te sugiero que dejes de usarlo y pienses mejor tu codigo... Vivirás más y mejor

Comment: Amigo Luis Diaz el resultado $variable me dice  0

Comment: @YanLenner puedes ayudarme anexando el objetivo de tu codigo porfavor? Para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Buenas Tardes @LuisDiaz, tengo un formulario de registro en donde quiero tomar el campo password y respuesta de seguridad y encriptarlo,sin necesidad de usar metodos de encriptacion comerciales o realizados por otra persona, entonces con los datos proporcionados a través de php llamo la funcion lenner que se encarga de encriptar el texto que puede llegar a un tamaño máximo de 10, cuando la función va a retornar el resultado que quiero, solo me muestra el primer caracter o sino tendría que concatenar el arreglo completo desde 0 hasta 9, quiero que me muestre el resultado completo 1 sola variabl

Comment: En esta pregunta principal se puede apreciar parte del codigo, *por ejemplo* si quiero guardar la password encriptada en una variable sería $mivariable=lenner($password); $mivariable2=lenner($respuesta); , lo que me sucede es que : "Que pasa si el arreglo es de tamaño 7, en las otras 3 posiciones restantes se guardaría un espacio en blanco y no es lo que deseo", porfavor no se sí me explique necesito ayuda